# Having a shortcut run with administrator permissions (win 7)

Tags: windows-7, administrator

Someimtes, On Windows 7, it's not enough to have the user be an administrator, you need to run programs specifically with administrative rights.  You do this by right clicking on the icon, and choosing "Run as administrator".

Is there a way that I choose a particular program to always "Run as administrator" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by following these steps:

- Right click on the shortcut
- Click on Properties
- Select the Compatibility tab
- At the bottom click "Change settings for all users"
- Again at the bottom select to "Run this program as an administrator"

Answer (score 1):

When you right-click on the shortcut, hit properties. Under the compatibility tab, you should have a checkbox to always run the thing as administrator.

Granted, I'm recounting this from memory, so the labels may not be exactly accurate. But the option is there in that general area.